# Should I check wether a passed list<T> is null

Tags: c#, list, null, generic-list

An extension method expects an open generic IEnumerable.

Should I check inside the method wether the list is null.

I have the opinion that a list must never be null but have count == 0.

How do you handle such a case?

UPDATE:

I forgot to mention that the method is a recursive method where the list is recursively called/passed of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you should check that. It's also fairly common pattern to throw in such case, especially in LINQ:

```
public static void MyExtension<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    }

    // ...
}
```

Handling empty list is much easier than handling list instance that is null. Think about it in this way; list with no items is simply empty collection - fairly common case. List that is null... represents what? *Exceptional situation*, and should be handled as such.

**Update:**

I looked around on what Microsoft has to say about my speculations that throwing ANE is common pattern (as opposed to letting CLR throw NRE - which at points might be too vague) and it seems to be correct. We can find at ANE [documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentnullexception%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that:

> ArgumentNullException (...) is provided so that application code **can differentiate** between exceptions caused by null arguments and exceptions caused by arguments that are not null.

And later, in framework design guidelines' [Exception Throwing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229030%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) section:

> Do report execution failures by throwing exceptions. If a member cannot successfully do what it is designed to do, that should be considered an **execution failure and an exception should be thrown**.

In your case, since you mentioned your method must never accept null list argument, it is simple *execution failure* situation.

Comment: I have updated my question. Why throw a Argument Exception if the framework would anyway throw a Null Exception if the method is called?

Comment: you advised about the ArgumentNullException before ChrisF did (He later edited his solution) :)

Comment: @Pascal: thanks. I've checked some design guidelines and it seems that throwing ANE is indeed recommended pattern. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Pascal: if you use them in your entire project then it definitely makes sense (especially considering they play very well with automatic test or documentation generation tools). It's rather *project-wide decision* (whether to use CC or not). Applying it for single method/case is probably not the best idea.

Answer (score 6):

It depends.

If the list being null is something you can't handle then test for it and raise a `ArgumentNullException`:

```
if (list == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException("some suitable message");
}
```

If the list being null is equivalent to the list existing but having no elements then allow for that:

```
if (list == null || list.Count() == 0)
{
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually I want to get an exception but sometimes (esp when using 3rd party code) handling null as an empty instance is more handy:

```
public static class FrameworkExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// null tolerant access to a Collection
    /// 
    /// usage:
    /// foreach (int i in returnArray.AsNotNull())
    /// {
    ///     // do some more stuff
    /// }
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of collection</typeparam>
    /// <param name="original"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IEnumerable<T> AsNotNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> original)
    {
        return original ?? new T[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Updated:

I believe you mean passing a list as a method parameter but in this case solution is obvious (even checking object itself):

```
public static void ExtensionMethod<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list,
                                      IEnumerable<T> anOtherlist)
{
    bool listItselfNotNull = list != null;
    bool anOtherListNotNull = anOtherList != null;
}
```

Comment: You *can* call an extension method on a null-object.

Comment: It is possible to use extension methods on `null`s.

Comment: wow nice to know, thanks all you guys! for -1 as well, it worth it :). Removed "null-tip"